# Cannot deserialize the JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type ' ' because type requires JSON object (e.g. {“name”:“value”}) to deserialize correctly

Tags: c#, json, api, xamarin

Tengo un api que regresa una consulta a de sql y luego convierte este a un json, pero al querer mostrarlo en Xamarin en un listview me manda que no puede deserealizarlo
Este es el Json que me regresa

```
[
  {
    "Fecha": "2020-06-25T00:00:00",
    "ClaveTractor": "0",
    "Caja": "",
    "Cliente": "#######",
    "DescripcionMovimiento": "#########",
    "Origen": "",
    "Destino": "",
    "Coordinador": "G####",
    "FechaAlta": "2020-06-25T10:36:49.62"
  },
  {
    "Fecha": "2020-06-25T00:00:00",
    "ClaveTractor": "0",
    "Caja": "",
    "Cliente": "#############",
    "DescripcionMovimiento": "#########",
    "Origen": "",
    "Destino": "",
    "Coordinador": "G######",
    "FechaAlta": "2020-06-25T10:10:56.283"
  }
]
```

Esta es la funcion con la que la mando llamar

```
 public async void GetJson()
        {
            string url = "http://192.168.1.116/ApiRest/api/Stored/" + "'043'?movimientos=1";
            //string UrlAll = url + ("'{0}'?movimientos={1}", Unidad.Text, 5);

            var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            string Json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            MovimientosList ObjMovmientos = new MovimientosList();
            if (Json != "")
            {
                ObjMovmientos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MovimientosList>(Json);
            }

            listviewMovimientos.ItemsSource = ObjMovmientos.Movimientos;
        }
```

he creado una clase con la pagina que converte el json en clases para usarla como lista

Esta es la clase

```
public class Movimiento
    {
        public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
        public string ClaveTractor { get; set; }
        public string Caja { get; set; }
        public string Cliente { get; set; }
        public string DescripcionMovimiento { get; set; }
        public string Origen { get; set; }
        public string Destino { get; set; }
        public string Coordinador { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaAlta { get; set; }
    }

    public class MovimientosList
    {
        public List<Movimiento> Movimientos { get; set; }
    }
```

Pero al ejecutarla este me manda el siguiente error, ya lo intente agregando la lista

```
ObjMovmientos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MovimientosList>>(Json);
```

Pero no muestra nada

Este es el error que manda

> 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
> 'LoginApp.Model.MovimientosList' because the type requires a JSON
> object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix this
> error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
> or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements
> a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can
> be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be
> added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta usar directo la clase simple algo como ser

```
var ObjMovmientos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movimiento>>(jsonString);
```

entonces quedaria

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string jsonString = @"[
                                  {
                                    'Fecha': '2020-06-25T00:00:00',
                                    'ClaveTractor': '0',
                                    'Caja': '',
                                    'Cliente': '#######',
                                    'DescripcionMovimiento': '#########',
                                    'Origen': '',
                                    'Destino': '',
                                    'Coordinador': 'G####',
                                    'FechaAlta': '2020-06-25T10:36:49.62'
                                  },
                                  {
                                    'Fecha': '2020-06-25T00:00:00',
                                    'ClaveTractor': '0',
                                    'Caja': '',
                                    'Cliente': '#############',
                                    'DescripcionMovimiento': '#########',
                                    'Origen': '',
                                    'Destino': '',
                                    'Coordinador': 'G######',
                                    'FechaAlta': '2020-06-25T10:10:56.283'
                                  }
                                ]";
        
        var ObjMovmientos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movimiento>>(jsonString);
        
        Console.WriteLine(ObjMovmientos.Count);
    }
}



public class Movimiento
{
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public string ClaveTractor { get; set; }
    public string Caja { get; set; }
    public string Cliente { get; set; }
    public string DescripcionMovimiento { get; set; }
    public string Origen { get; set; }
    public string Destino { get; set; }
    public string Coordinador { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaAlta { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hola Leandro Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, efectivamente me lo muestra ahora solo no puedo mostrarlo en un listview en XamarinForms, sabes si hay alguna manera de modificar el json y agregarle un titulo 

Movimiento: {
'Fecha' : x 

y asi porder agregarlo a un listview por el titulo

Comment: Entiendo estas asignando al ItemSource la lista directa porque ahora ya no hay una propiedad. Pero no entendi que seria esto del titulo o la fecha. Estas seguro que el grid de xamarin define esto en base a la entidad? No sea que debas definir algo diferente en el xaml